# Can someone explain this JavaScript auto executing function?

Tags: javascript, logic

```
var foo = (function(){
  var x = 0;
  return function(){return x++;};
})()
```

Why the var x = 0 expression only runs once is my biggest misunderstanding about this.

Comment: i think he wants to know about the javascript closure.

Comment: @pastjean, Yeah, I mention that in my answer actually. :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code:

```
var foo = (function(){
  var x = 0;
  return function(){return x++;};
})()
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
function f(){
  var x = 0;
  return function(){return x++;};
}
var foo = f();
```

It's easy to see, when you break it up like this, that the function `f()` is only called once.  It defines `x`, and then returns a *new* function that is defined *inside* the local scope of `f`.  This new function is often called an "anonymous function" (meaning that it has no name) or a "closure".  In truth, *all* functions in javascript are "closures" -- whether or not they are named.  The term "closure" simply means that the function retains access to the variables that were defined in the parent function's scope -- even after the parent function has exited.

So now, `foo` contains the new function (the closure) that was returned from `f`.  You can call `foo()` as many times as you like -- and each time you do, `x` will be returned and post-incremented. Since `x` exists in the closure's parent scope, its value will persist across multiple calls to the closure.

What's more... no other code now has access to `x` once `f()` has exited -- this basically means that `x` is now the "private data" of the closure.  Pretty neat huh?

Comment: how are all functions in JS closures? `function(x){return x;}` is the identity _function_, not a closure - it requires no lexical state.

Comment: @tobyodavies: But even the "identity function" still retains a reference to its parent scope -- the fact that it does not *use* anything from the parent scope doesn't mean that the function is somehow a different kind of entity.  In some other languages, functions and closures are different language-level constructs.  In javascript all functions are closures.

Comment: a closure is a first-class function with _free variables_ that are bound in the lexical environment. The implementation is irrelevant to any _language level question_ because you can have different implementations of the same language. It is an important part of the definition of a closure that the function has free variables i.e. _"uses"_ its lexical environment. I'm fairly sure nowhere in the ECMAScript standard does it require an implementation to keep a pointer to lexical scope if the function doesn't need it.

Comment: @tobyodavies: any version of ECMA that still supports `eval()`, will require that *all* functions retain a reference to the parent scope.  There may be other examples - but that's the obvious one.  [here's proof on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/WFeb6/1/).

Comment: Fair point, didn't realize JS `eval` used callers lexical scope... un-1ed

Answer (score 6):

The variable `foo` is being assigned to the result of the self-executing function, which goes as follows:

Declares a variable named `x` initialized to `0`.
   Returns a *function* that, when invoked, will increment the value of `x`.

So at this point, `foo` references a *function*.

The way you would invoke this is:

```
foo();
```

The first time this is invoked, the value returned will be `0`, then `1`, `2`...

*Well, **wait a minute...**, shouldn't it be `1`, `2`, `3`...?*

You are on the right track, but the reason why in this case this *isn't* true is because of the difference between **pre-increment** and **post-increment**. (`++var` vs `var++`). The difference is that the result of a **pre-increment** is the variable's value after increment, while the result of a **post-increment** is the variable's value *before* increment.

This example illustrates the concept of [***closures***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), which essentially means that inner functions have access to the variables defined in their surrounding functions.

Comment: Slight correction, it'll be `0`, the *result* of the increment is `1`, but the return is the original, `0`.  If it was `++x`, you'd get `1`, `2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down... First we define an anonymous function:

```
(function() { ... })
```

We then immediately execute it:

```
(function() { ... })()
```

The result of this execution is another function:

```
function(){return x++;}
```

And the x=0 is captured by the closure when we created the above function. We then assign this resulting function to foo:

```
var foo = function(){return x++;}
```

With the value of x captured by the closure. Whenever foo is executed, x is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function gets invoked immediately by the `()` that follows it (passing in no parameters).  That function when executed is returning another function, which has it's own `x` variable that gets incremented when run.

So `foo()` is going to be `0` the first run, `1` the second, etc, since that `x` it was created with continues to increment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this case `x` is a local variable within the block/closure assigned to the `foo` object. One that gets incremented when you call `foo()`.

Check it out in action - http://jsfiddle.net/3X283/

Comment: -1 this is not an object, it is a closure. they are related but different. and this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) theere are two functions defined - the inner one (which is the closure) and the outer one which creates and returns the closure.

Your code calls the outer function immediately and assigns the *result* (the  closure) to `foo`.

Note the code inside the closure does not include the statement `var x = 0;` thus when you call `foo()` it only executes the code *inside* the closure (`return x++;`)

The `x` referred to in here is the one instantiated in the call. What makes closures interesting is that this *x* is different between invocations of the outer function - consider the example below. foo and bar will increment independantly of one another because they reference *different* `x`s

```
function makeClosure(){
  var x = 0;
  return function(){return x++;};
}

var foo = makeClosure();
var bar = makeClosure();

foo(); //returns 0
foo(); //returns 1
bar(); //returns 0
foo(); //returns 2
```